# seek() and tell() in text mode, file handling python

Tags: python-3.x, io, file-handling, fseek, ftell

I learnt that f.tell() returns an integer giving the file object’s current position in the file represented as number of bytes from the beginning of the file when in binary mode and an opaque number when in text mode.
but here tell() is changing the output anyone know how?

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Harshit\Desktop\file15.txt","w+") as f:
    a=f.read()
    f.write("hello1")
    f.write("hello2last")
    f.seek(0,0)
    f.write("HELLO3")
    f.write("HELLO3")
    print(f.read(1))
    f.write("added")
    f.seek(0,0)
    f.write("55555")
print(a,type(a))
```

output:

```
555551hello2lastHELLO3HELLO3added
```

also using tell() before read(1) i.e  print(f.tell(),f.read(1))  changes output to :

```
555553HELLO3lastadded
```

whereas in binary mode it gives the perfect output as expected

```
555553HELLO3ladded
```

why i m getting faulty outputs in text mode?